# unsubscribe? what is happening with angular component that was injected into MatDialog or MatBottomSheet when closed?

Tags: angular, rxjs

my quastion is about subscription on components events injected into matdialog or bottomsheet
for example lets say that i do

```
 NewUser() {
const formData = {
  Title: 'NewUser',
  ValidateBtn: false,
  FormFields:
    [
      new InputField('Login', InputType.Text, [Validators.required, Validators.min(8), Validators.max(8) ] ),
      new InputField('name', InputType.Text,  [Validators.required, Validators.min(3), Validators.max(50) ] ),
      new InputField('surname', InputType.Text, [Validators.required, Validators.min(3), Validators.max(50) ])
    ]
 };

const dialogRef =  this.bottomSheet.open(DynamicFormsComponent,  { data: formData  }    );
 dialogRef.instance.EmitFormData.subscribe(data => {
 //post data to server
 dialogRef.dismiss();
 });
}
```

and that works fine - input field is my class helping generate form fields in my DynamicFormsComponent

but i read a lot about subscriptions and unsubscribe etc. i Know hows its works / that `unsubscribe()` is good practise in most cases

in this `EmitFormData` i do `complete()` at end so there is no need to unsubscribe

but WHAT if user does not click submit on this DynamicFormsComponent, and instead of click somwhere outside this component - on this `'blur'` / Backdrop ...

bottomSheet/ matdialog will close itself
but what with this subscription ? should i unsubscribe on close this `matdialog` ? or angular do this / delete this `dialogRef` and subscription with it ?

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

For unsubscribing from custom Observables (often necessary to avoid memory leaks), I strongly advise the following pattern:

- create a Subject which emits when a component is destroyed
- add a `takeUntil` operator to each Observable used within the component

```js
private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();
// ...
ngOnInit() {
  const myObs$ = this.myService.getObs().pipe(  // example of Observable in component
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    // other Observable logic here
  );
}
// ...
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks - that is good option but not related to my quastion - my quastion is what is happening with this component inside matdialog/bottomsheet when it is dissmissed

Comment: I'm not sure it matters. I'd avoid putting logic in the `subscribe` call, and instead use a `pipe` to handle data emissions, especially if the Observable only emits once, allowing you to add `take(1)` to make the Observable complete automatically. Basic rule of thumb is always find a way to unsubscribe ^^

Comment: *unsubscribe/complete the Observable

Comment: yes i known but in this case i does not known if even this take 1 will be hit - it may not be if user does not click submit to emit this one ? im thinkink about case when user just dismiss this matdialog so no emission?